# Pandas transform with custom function

Tags: python, pandas, transform

Here is my simple code

```
def custom_func(x):
    for el in x.index:
        print(el)
    return None

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['F','F','F','K','K'], 'B':[54,87,35,25,82],
                       'C':[56,78,0,14,13]})

mask = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(custom_func)
```

It generates the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/temp3.py", line 59, in <module>
    consecutive_check()
  File "C:/Users/temp3.py", line 56, in consecutive_check
    mask = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(custom_func)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2763, in transform
    result[indexer] = res
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

What is wrong, why do I get this error message.

Comment: try to replace `None` --> `np.nan`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is because your function always returns `None`, regardless of the input. Could you provide a more complete description of what you expect as the final result?